# How can i configure magmi and import bulk images

Tags: magento-1.9, import, image, magmi

How can I configure MAGMI for my site, and how to use it for the **bulk images import**, and products.

Comment: did you uploaded products before using magmi ?

Comment: just put sku and images path correctly in csv excel sheet & place the images in proper path & upload it.

Comment: i am new to magmi, initially how can i configure

Comment: pls go through this link : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/R2XJM9w.png

Comment: how can i fill this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43677/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: enter db name, username & password and path and save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow this [link](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for complete information from scratch to configuration, uploading & then you can enter the SKU in one column & image name in another column and upload the excel sheet.

[image]

Comment: How can i import images for my store 1, actually i have two store?

Comment: @Rathinam please follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195637/magmi-multi-store-import

Comment: this is my stores: https://snag.gy/rGlAPY.jpg

Comment: and magmi import format :  sku : 123 websites : main,, is right?

Comment: @Rathinam enter the store code in excel sheets, in that link they gave an example, you can follow that.....

Comment: after adding code not working.. sku: 123, website: english,,,, is right?

Comment: @Rathinam in the first row of excel sheet. you need to mention `store` below that , you need to mention your store codes..... go to system > Manage stores > than click on any store , than you can see store code here : http://prntscr.com/g3a6g1 , in the image `india` is store code, you need to mention the same in excel sheet and check......

Comment: My store Code screen shot : https://snag.gy/rGlAPY.jpg, csv screen shot : https://snag.gy/ACKw5j.jpg,, and my products image present inside the folder media/import.. still not working

Comment: Is my workout right?

Comment: no , before sku, you should mention `store` as mentioned in that answer.....

Comment: can i get csv haeder name like sku, image_label

Comment: you need to follow as here  : http://prntscr.com/g3ad8i

Comment: here store mean what? let consider my screen shot : https://snag.gy/rGlAPY.jpg

Comment: @Rathinam there, in 3rd column.....  `english` is store code of store view : `English` , i cant see 2nd one......

Comment: is right : https://snag.gy/Q9ZEme.jpg

Comment: @Rathinam ya, try uploading once.....

Comment: its not working.

Comment: store sku image image_label small_image thumbnail media_gallery
english 420065_01 +/420065-1.jpg abcd /420065-1.jpg /420065-1.jpg /420065-2.jpg;/420065-3.jpg;/420065-4.jpg;/420065-5.jpg;/420065-6.jpg

Comment: okay, i dont have any idea, you can post new question with what you tried......

Comment: okay....let me check

Answer (score 0):

> **Add Below Data To Your Import Data Array**

```
$importData['image'] = "https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/oly_testwow_stage.jpg";
$importData['image_label'] =  "base Image label";

$importData['small_image'] = "https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/oly_testwow_stage.jpg";
$importData['small_image_label'] = "small Image label";

$importData['thumbnail'] = "https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/oly_testwow_stage.jpg";
$importData['thumbnail_label'] = "Thumbnail Image label";

$importData['media_gallery'] = "https://cdn.hackernoon.com/hn-images/0*xMaFF2hSXpf_kIfG.jpg::TestImage1;https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/befbcde0-9b36-11e6-95b9-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg::testImage2"
```

**Note: Image attributes processor must be check (ON) from magmi setting in your Magmi Profile.**

[image]